# Uninstall TFS on Windows Server 2016 fails silently

Tags: windows, uninstall, team-foundation-server

I have a Windows Server 2016 Standard with Team Foundation Server Server 2013 Update 5 installed.

When I go to Add/remove programs and click Uninstall for TFS 2013, nothing happens. There is no error message and the program is still installed.

I have looked in the Windows Event log but could not see any error messages.

I have rebooted the server several times also.

The server was recently restored from a backup. Before the backup, I was able to perform the uninstall without problems.

How can I find out more about why uninstalling does not work?

Comment: Maybe check to confirm that everything was restored fully related to TFS within the installation directory. It may be that it is referencing an uninstall msi package or something like that and since it is missing, it doesn't do anything. Run process monitor and see what events trigger, etc. when you click uninstall. Check for the registry location of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall.` and see if you see any uninstall pointers for TFS and compare the keys with other installed packages and see how those are typically structured. Quick thoughts.

Comment: Strange. I started Process Monitor and then retried uninstalling. And this time it worked.

Comment: I don't know TFS that well but perhaps there were some changes to the data repository of the restore you completed and it took time to roll back any uncommitted changes or something like that after the restore for uncommitted changes that were backed up, & maybe it doesn't allow uninstall to even start when it's in that state. This is just a guess but trying to think logically why this could have happened & since you rebooted several times, perhaps the rollback operation kept restarting and by the time you did it this last time, everything rolled back & it was in a state that allows uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

I ran Process Monitor in capture mode and retried uninstalling. This time it worked... not sure if ProcMon had anything to do with it though.